# how to store multiple images in an array before inserting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have an upload function that is working with one or multiple files able to upload to a folder and then insert an index to mysql.  How do I store multiple images as an array?

```
//This upload code to allow users to upload specific files 
<?php
$user_id = $_SESSION['lt_user_id'];
$user_code = $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }

$host="server.mysql.com"; 
$username="user";
$password="password";
$db_name="db01";
$tbl_name="upload_data";

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT into $tbl_name (ID, USER_CODE, FILE_NAME, FILE_SIZE, FILE_TYPE) VALUES('$user_id','$user_code','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";


 $desired_dir="../backup1Jan2013/images/";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
 mysql_query($sql);         
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}



// close connection
mysql_close();


?>


<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: For some reason it did not post right but I have a file upload function that is working with one or multiple files.  I am able to upload the file (or files) into a folder and then  insert the file information (ie, filename, filesize & filetype) into a table in mysql.  

However, when multiple images are uploaded at the same time the filesize is being inserted as “0”.

Can you provide me an example of the best way to capture ALL these file attributes when working with multiple selected files?  Perhaps storing each files properties in an array?

Comment: Can you post the HTML of the upload form?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to store multiple images in the same field of a database.

Instead, I would store the images in a folder in the file system and store the folder's location in your mysql table.

Comment: The images are store in the file system but the issue is I would need to associate the images with the user id so I need an array so I would  query much easier.  How would I code your way?  That is the issue because I am not really sure how.